How can I exclude a crate from compilation when a feature is disabled?
I have a Rust project that follows a structure:
- main_crate (features = "x")
  - driver_crate (features = "x")
    - x_crate
    ...
  ...

In my main_crate, I have a feature flag x that I enable by default which is propagated to the driver_crate via the following setup in main_crate/Cargo.toml:
[features]
x = ["driver-crate/x"]

# default = ["x"]

The driver_crate/Cargo.toml specifies the x dependency as optional in the following way:
[dependencies]
x-crate = { path = "../x-crate", optional = true }

[features]
x = ["dep:x-crate"]

Suppose that I run cargo build --no-default-features, my expectation is that now that x is no longer enabled by default, Cargo should now treat the x dependency as false and hence not even attempt to compile it as part of the project. Instead, cargo still adds x_crate as part of the compilation process.
Furthermore, I verified that "x" crate is not in the "dependency" tree when I do the following command:
cargo tree -p main_crate | grep "x_crate"

It is however present when I specifically enable x:
cargo tree -p main_crate -F "x" | grep "x_crate"
│   │   ├── x_crate v0.1.0 (/src/x_crate)

Is there a way to ensure that x_crate is not compiled at all when feature x is not specified?
Update: I realised why it's included in the compilation. My project is using a virtual manifest that specifies that the members of the workspace are src/* which automatically includes x:
[workspace]
members = [
  "src/*",

How can I dynamically include/exclude x_crate as a dependency when I specify x feature flag to the workspace?

What you say you want to happen is what happens. When --no-default-features is passed when building the root crate, then x-crate is not built. What are you seeing that suggests x-crate is being compiled? Perhaps there is another dependency using it or enabling the feature?

Are these crates all part of the same workspace? If they are, do you build a workspace (with cargo build in its root) or a specific project?

@kmdreko I tried running with —no-default-features and commenting out the line which specifies x as default but to no avail.

@Cerberus yes they are all part of the same workspace. The diagram I provided tries to illustrate the dependency tree of the crates, not sure if it was overly clear.

@kmdreko In my particular use case, I am testing this project on a machine that doesn't support x, when I try to compile it, one of the static_asserts fires indicates that this machine configuration is not supported. I think this is a good indicator that the crate is being compiled.

@feds01 try for the sanity check remove all folders with build artifacts and rebuild

@AlexeyS.Larionov I realised that it is being included because it is automatically specified in my workspace manifest regardless of feature set specified, is there anyway to specify features in the virtual manifest of the workspace?

The crate is being compiled because in a workspace, Cargo by default builds all packages.
You can build only a specific package (and its dependencies) with cargo build --package <package> (cargo build -p <package>), or set a default package for all cargo builds via workspace.default-members.
